# update angular 8 to 9

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, agm-core

I am trying to update from 8 to 9 I get this:

```
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 85 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/material @ "9.2.4" (was "8.2.3")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cdk @ "9.2.4" (was "8.2.3")...
UPDATE package.json (6742 bytes)
⠸ Installing packages...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@9.1.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^9.1.13" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^9.0.0" from @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@6.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-material-extensions/password-strength
npm ERR!     @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@"^6.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   15 more (@angular/flex-layout, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!   @agm/core@"^1.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @agm/core@"^1.0.0-beta.7" from @agm/js-marker-clusterer@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@agm/js-marker-clusterer
npm ERR!     @agm/js-marker-clusterer@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!     @agm/core@"^1.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @agm/core@"^1.0.0-beta.7" from @agm/js-marker-clusterer@1.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@agm/js-marker-clusterer
npm ERR!       @agm/js-marker-clusterer@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!
```

When I run
`NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 npx @angular/cli@9 update @angular/material@9` I get this:

```
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 85 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/material @ "9.2.4" (was "8.2.3")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cdk @ "9.2.4" (was "8.2.3")...
UPDATE package.json (6742 bytes)
⠸ Installing packages...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@9.1.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^9.1.13" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^9.0.0" from @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@6.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-material-extensions/password-strength
npm ERR!     @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@"^6.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   15 more (@angular/flex-layout, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!   @agm/core@"^1.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @agm/core@"^1.0.0-beta.7" from @agm/js-marker-clusterer@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@agm/js-marker-clusterer
npm ERR!     @agm/js-marker-clusterer@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!     @agm/core@"^1.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @agm/core@"^1.0.0-beta.7" from @agm/js-marker-clusterer@1.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@agm/js-marker-clusterer
npm ERR!       @agm/js-marker-clusterer@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!
```

Comment: I believe you have to solve the dependency conflict with angular google maps package, `agm`, update that package to a version compatible to Angular 9 and after that, try upgrading Angular to v9

Comment: You could try with the `--force` flag `NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 npx @angular/cli@9 update @angular/material@9 --force`. This will install stuff, but dependencies may not work. So use at your own risk...

Comment: Your other option, is to fix the dependencies that it is complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how npm dependencies work. In the package.json of agm core you will see that Angular ^9.1.0 is used. Therefore you need to run the same or above version of Angular 9 in order to successfully upgrade.

However, looks like your maps package only supports Angular up to version 10. Considering Angular is releasing version 18 soon, you might want to drop your old package for a newer implementation.

In your package.json, update versions of all angular components to 9.1.0 or above.

Answer (score 0):

#### Understanding the Error

You can fix your dependencies by understanding the error. Lets take a look at what the first dependency is telling us:

```
npm ERR! While resolving: @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@9.1.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^9.1.13" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^9.0.0" from @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@6.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-material-extensions/password-strength
npm ERR!     @angular-material-extensions/password-strength@"^6.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   15 more (@angular/flex-layout, @angular/forms, ...)
```

- `@agm/core` has an incorrect formatted semantic version dependency in your `package.json`.

  - It is asking for version `^9.0.0` of `@angular/common` on line 5.
  - You are providing `^9.1.13` on line 2.

Yes, these are the same major version, but the semantic version is not the same.

You should be able to fix this by doing one of two things:

1. Find a version of `@agm/core` that has a semantic version of `^9.1.13` for `@angular/common`.
2. Change your semantic version to `^9.0.0` in the `package.json`.

Now you just need to do this will all the errors that get reported.

---

#### Overrides

If `ng update` is doing this for you, you can always provide an override in your `package.json`.

Doing it like this, will override **ALL** references to `@angular/common` in any package, with angular this is probably what you want.

```json
{
  "overrides": {
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.13"
  }
}
```

With other packages this may not be what you want, and in that case you can override just for that package. In this example, `@org/package`'s dependence for `other/package` will use `^1.2.3`, by anything else that uses `@other/package` will use whatever it asks for.

```json
{
  "overrides": {
    "@org/package": {
      "@other/package": "^1.2.3"
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Last Resort

The last thing to do, which I would do as a last resort, is to add `--force` to the end of the command. This will force it to install the version even if the sematic versions do not match in this case from the example above `^9.1.13`.

```
NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 npx @angular/cli@9 update @angular/material@9 --force
```